# "$file" got invalid value: How do I upload files in graphql using react native if I'm already using GraphQLClient (rtk-query) instead of ApolloClient?

Tags: react-native, file-upload, graphql, apollo-client, rtk-query

Our backend team created a file upload endpoint following the documentation here: https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client

So the mutation looks like:

```
mutation FileUpload($file: Upload!) {
  single_upload(file: $file) {
    uri
    content_type
  }
}
```

I generate a file using `codegen.ts` to create an endpoint which I inject to my createApi:

```
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithErrorHandlingGQL,
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

And this is the graphqlbasequery where it uses the GraphQLClient:

```
export const rawBaseQueryGQL: BaseQueryFn<
  IGQLBaseQuery,
  unknown,
  Partial<ClientError & { errorCode: number }>
> = async ({ document, variables }, api, extraOptions) => {
  const client = new GraphQLClient(
    process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL,
    {
      credentials: "include",
    }
  );

  client.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  client.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  client.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

  const query = graphqlRequestBaseQuery<
    Partial<ClientError & { errorCode: number }>
  >({
    client,

    customErrors: ({ name, stack, response }) => {
      const { errorMessage = "", errorCode = 500 } = response?.errors?.length
        ? response?.errors[0]?.extensions
        : {};

      return {
        name,
        message: errorMessage,
        errorCode,
        stack,
      };
    },
  });

  return query({ document, variables }, api, extraOptions);
};
```

Now, I call the mutation like so:

```
  import { ReactNativeFile } from 'apollo-upload-client';
  import { api as FileUploadApi, FileUploadMutation } from '../../../api/mutations/FileUpload.generated';

  ...

  const [fileUpload] = FileUploadApi.endpoints.FileUpload.useMutation()

  ...

  const file = new ReactNativeFile({
      uri: ans.uri,
      name: ans.filename,
      type: ans.contentType,});
  return await fileUpload({ file: file })
       .unwrap()
       .then(async (response: FileUploadMutation) => {
             return { success: true }
        })
       .catch((error) => {
            return { success: false}
        });
```

However, I get `Error: Error: Variable "$file" got invalid value,  Upload value invalid`.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue yesterday, but I managed to solved this in two parts.

I was not able to transfer my `.xlsx.writeBuffer()` file in the form of a buffer to apollo-server-express v3.12.0. The error that I had was:

> "Message: Variable "$file" got invalid value { type: "Buffer", data: [1,2,3 ... 4567 more items] }; Upload value invalid.,"

The error seems to be coming from the server side, where it seems to only be accepting a File type object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) for the Upload scalar. For starters, check that you are receiving a Promise `{ filename, mimetype, encoding, createReadStream }` in your client side. I managed to resolve this by the following:

```
const fileA = new File([mybufferdata], myfilename)

await mutation({
   variables: {
    file: fileA
   }
})
```

If done correctly, you should be able to see the promise object in your server.

The second step is actually passing the data over. You might need to append it over as a stringified JSON and then parse it over at the client side. I amended my mutation as such, where buffer is a stringified JSON object:

```
await mutation({
   variables: {
    file: fileA,
    buffer: JSON.stringify({mybufferdata})
   }
})
```

In the server side, use `JSON.parse(buffer)` to get the contents of the data that you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Honestly, we ended up using a non-graphql approach to file upload and just used Expo's FileSystem.uploadAsync() but hopefully, someone else can use your answer.